# Type I and type II errors

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Let $X \sim \text{uniform}(0,\theta)$ we are testing $H_0: \theta = 1$ vs $H_1: \theta >1$ If we know that we reject $H_0$ if $X>0.9$

(1) find $\alpha$, the type I error

(2)Suppose that $\theta=1.1$. Find $\beta$ the type II error probability

I would appreciate some advise on solving this.

for (1) I thought I could start with.

$\alpha=P(X>0.9|H_0)$ Which is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ if $X>0.9$ as given in the problem. Do I use the cdf and integrate?

I honestly don't know how to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The type I error is the probability to reject $H_0$ under $H_0$, so $\alpha=P(X>0.9|\theta = 1)$.
Under $H_0$, $X\sim U(\lbrack 0,1\rbrack )$, so you just have to determine the probability that a $U(\lbrack 0,1\rbrack )$ distributed random variable to be greater than $0.9$.

The type II is the probability not to reject $H_0$ when $H_0$ is wrong.

Comment: Ok I reviewed some concepts on uniform distribution, and $P(X>0.9)=P(X \leq 1)-P(X \leq .09)= 1-0.9=0.1$ which gives a $0.1$  value for $\alpha$ and a $0.8181818$ value for $\beta$  when $\theta = 1.1$which I think makes more sense.